# Is there a rom that can upgrade any android device?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, inet

I want to upgrade my tablet to android lollipop. I can't seen to find a rom that can fit my model (wing-inet). So I want to know if you could just update it with any rom.

Comment: No, the ROM needs to support the specific hardware in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you cant do that. 
Detalied answer: every rom is created for specific device, it contains all drivers etc required for device to work. If you use rom from other device, in best scenario it simply won't work, in worst it will brick your device.